# Minimum value of a function of two variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Find the minimum value of the function

$f(x, y) = x^2 + y^2$

subject to one equality constraint

$g(x, y) =x^2 -y^2 - 5x + 20 =0$

and one inequality constraint:

$u(x, y) = 2x + y \ge6$

I think that I will have to use Lagrange multipliers to solve this. But I have not seen any question with two different type of constraints and that is why I am not getting how to apply Lagrange multipliers here.

Please help.

Comment: Let $L=f(x,y) - \lambda_1 g(x,y) - \lambda_2 (u(x,y)-6)$.  Find partial derivatives with respect to $\{x,y,\lambda_1, \lambda_2\}$.  $\cdots$  The second constraint is an inequality constraint.  You may need to exercise extra care there.

Comment: You can remove the inequality. The constraint $2x+y\ge6$ doesn't contain the origin. If you know the general shape of the paraboloid $f(x,y)$, it's not hard to see that the minimum must lie in the plane $2x+y=6$. OTOH you can fold one constraint into the other, instead minimizing $2x^2-5x+20$ (substitute $y^2$) subject to the inequality.